# If I buy the game on one platform, can I continue play it on any platform?

Tags: knockout-city

Once you hit rank 25 in the free trial edition of Knockout City, you're forced to buy the normal or deluxe edition of the game to continue playing.  This is fine, but since I want to play on a few platforms I'd like to know if buying the game on any platform will give me unlimited access on all platforms.  Otherwise I'll have to pick the one I want access to the most right now.

During the block party trial period, the game featured cross-progression between platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, no.  Looks like I need to buy at least the base edition of the game again to even play on another platform.  Seems that if I were to do so my progression would continue to be shared between platforms (with the exception of deluxe cosmetics), but I'm just getting a 'you've reached the max free trial rank' splash screen.

Disappointing.

Comment: If you were expecting buying it on one console to let you download it for free on other consoles, that was an unrealistic expectation.  Sometimes buying a game will give access to it on several consoles made by the same company, but that is as far as it goes normally.  I’m not aware of any case where buying one version of a game lets you play it on EVERYTHING it has been released on (unless it was exclusive to one company’s consoles).

Comment: The closest to cross platform is when GOG did a partnership with Steam where having the game on Steam registered it on GOG also, but that seems to be no longer happening.

The main reason is because each of the system gets absolutely nothing by offering you the game for free. If you bought it on Sony Playstation, there is exactly 0 incentive for any other platform to give you the game. There is also negative incentive to do that because it implies all the platforms need to connect to each other to figure out when to give you the game for free.